# HTML LISTBOXES & PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP, HTML & web development in general.

I was trying to get a listbox to read entries in from a associative array, which I managed to do.
The problem is that, I can't seem to access the correct value, when an option is selected. It always seems generate the same response ("London"), regardless of which option is chosen. I tried replacing $city with ["listBox"], but the output was 'selected="selected"', $city seemed closer to what I was wanting, so I changed it back.

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out the reason why, if somebody can help me with this, I would appreciate it, thank you in advance.

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html lang="en"/>`    
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Array Section: ex5.php</title>
    <charset = "utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // Create an associate array 
        $countriesWithCities = array(
            "Japan" => "Tokyo",
            "Mexico" => "Mexico City",
            "USA" => "New York City",
            "India" => "Mumbai",
            "South Korea" => "Seoul",
            "China" => "Shanghai",
            "Nigeria" => "Lagos",
            "Brazil" => "Sao Paulo",
            "Egypt" => "Cairo",
            "England" => "London"
        );
        ?>
        <form action="ex5b.php" method="POST" />
        <h1>Ex5b.php </h1>
        <h3>"listBox">Please choose a country from the list box. </h3>
        <select name="listBox" id="listBox" size="9" >
            <?php foreach ($countriesWithCities as $individualCountry => $city) { ?>
                <option value= <?php $city; ?> selected="selected">
                    <?php echo $individualCountry;
                    >
                } ?></option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Submit form" />
        <form>
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST["submitButton"])) {
                echo "You chose " . $city;
            }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You indent code with four spaces to format it.  I've fixed it for you.  Remember this for the future.

Comment: What does $_POST contains?

Comment: @Jocelyn, when I did it originally with $city, the response was "London" (no matter what option I chose). I changed "$city" to ["listBox"], and it only displayed 'selected="selected" '. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a echo before $city, and an extra closing > after $individualCountry.  As well you had the closing `</option>` tag after the closing brace (}) in the foreach loop.

```
<select name="listBox" id="listBox" size="9" > 
<?php 
    foreach($countriesWithCities as $individualCountry=>$city)
    {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $city; ?>" selected="selected"> <?php echo $individualCountry; ?>
    </option> 
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Was going to say you were missing quotes around the city, but you seem to have noticed that ;) *Now* you can has a +1. Although I'd probably still htmlspecialchars both those vars in case he puts anything weird in there (like quotes or angle brackets).

Comment: Gerbenny, I used Control + K, for each line, and it still didn't come out right.
Did you use Control + K for each line, or just once (and paste the entire code into the speech marks?).

Answer (score 0):

correct code

```
<!DOCTYPE html lang="en">
<?php
$countriesWithCities = array(
   "Japan" => "Tokyo",
   "Mexico" => "Mexico City",
   "USA" => "New York City",
   "India" => "Mumbai",
   "South Korea" => "Seoul",
   "China" => "Shanghai",
   "Nigeria" => "Lagos",
   "Brazil" => "Sao Paulo",
   "Egypt" => "Cairo",
   "England" => "London"
);
?>
<form action="ex5b.php" method="POST">
<h1>Ex5b.php </h1>
<h3>Please choose a country from the list box. </h3>
<select name="city" id="listBox">
   <?php foreach($countriesWithCities as $individualCountry=>$city){?>
   <option value=<?php echo $city; ?>> <?php echo $individualCountry; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
   <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Submit form" />
</form>

<?php if(isset($_POST["submitButton"]))
{
   echo "You chose " . $_POST['city'];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**corrections made**

1. you probably copied this code from a book (PDF?) so starting PHP tag after doctype was missing along with array name.
2. Form was missing closing tag
3. `<select>` was missing `name` attribute
4. you were looking for `$city` in PHP code instead of `$_POST['city']`

and a lot happened after I copied code from your question or I just copied the incomplete code :D

Comment: Ejay the code was not copied, I did it myself, borrowed lines from various sources, hence the many mistakes. Thanks for taking the time to correct it.

Comment: ah, sorry for my assumption :) the "ex5b.php" part drove me off :D

Comment: you got this to work without the selected attribute? Now I'm puzzled, the books I've read all say you need it. tried to access country by using $_POST['individualCountry'], that failed too. So I'm again puzzled how it worked for $_POST['city']?

Comment: `<select name="city" id="listBox">` the browser posts the value of selected `<option>` to the server-side script, and it is available as an index of `$_POST` array in PHP with key name equal to `name` attribute of the `<select>` (almost same is the case with all HTML elements), hence you get `$_POST['city']`

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it makes more sense to me now. So why do the books keep on stressing use the select attribute to ensure that the choice is registered?
The 5b, is because I did 5, it wasn't working, I took a copy to see if I could get it to work. Hence the name 5b. I was practising what I had learned. I do not (yet) have an assignment to submit. Just trying to improve my understanding, nothing else.

Comment: That's for selecting the same element _automatically_ that you selected before pressing `submit form` button. If you didn't notice, the page always displays "japan" after page load. _leaving "automatic selection after page load" for you as a practice ;)_

Comment: I did notice that it went back to Japan, and didn't know the reason why. That I will have to research, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value= <?php $city; ?> selected="selected">
```

Change to

```
<option value= <?php echo $city; ?> selected="selected">
```

Comment: If you ask me I would remove the selected attribute. Just saying

Comment: Ejay and Gerbenny, the code you pasted works fine. Thanks to everyone who stopped to help & therefore improve my understanding.